# Rails action caching question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, action-caching

I'm not quite sure how to ensure my caching is working, but I'm pretty sure it's not.  I have a users controller with an index action that I'm action caching until a new user is created.  Here's the code:

```
UsersController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :index
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    expires_action :index
    ...
  end
end
```

Now, in my logs when I access the `index` action, I see:

```
Cached fragment hit: views/localhost:3000/users (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as [#<ActionController::Filters::AroundFilter:0xe2fbd3 @identifier=nil, @kind=:filter, @options={:only=>#<Set: {"index", "new"}>, :if=>nil, :unless=>nil}, @method=#<Proc:0x186cb11@/Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3/gems/actionpack-2.3.10/lib/action_controller/caching/actions.rb:64>>] did_not_yield.
```

I'm not sure what the `filter chain halted ... did_not_yield` is all about and I also see that that `select * from users`... is getting called each time, which is not what I expected.

Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on here and why this isn't behaving as I would expect?  ie. why the User.all would be running when that whole action's output should have been cached ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `filter chain halted` message means that there is an around filter that stops the action from calling. This is likely to be the action cache, that stops the real action from happening. It did not *yield* to the action, because it found something in the cache, as suggested by the message above it.

The `User.all` shouldn't be run at all, because it is in the action, but any before filters will get run. If your page is behind some form of authentication, than the authentication check might have triggered the SQL call. So you might want to double check where the SQL log really comes from.

Also, the proper syntax (according to the rails guide at least) for expiring is:

```
expire_action :action => :index
```

More info: [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#action-caching)

Comment: It appears you were right, the select was from my auth... should have looked closer.  Thanks for the info on the logs though, it wasn't obvious to me that the `halt` and `did not yield` was in fact pulling from the cache